# Download RDL files from Report Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I'm trying to download some rdl files from a production server(SQL 2008), but i'm not able to do it, i have tried to follow this [site](http://sql-articles.com/articles/general/download-export-rdl-files-from-report-server/), which should be strait forward. But then i push the download button, it starts during something, but then stop, also i'm not getting any permission errors or anything at all, the screen stays the same. It is the same then i go in manage. Are there anybody who have any suggestions?
[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is have the Network Tab looks like in IE F12 Dev tools![image]
And the console just look like this:

```
HTML1202: http://dkasql-001/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fSFOS%2fRTF+Report&ViewMode=Detail is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked. 
Folder.aspx
```

Comment: Press F12 in IE to bring up the console. Then click on the Network tab and press play. Now try and download the rdl and see if the console gives you any information into why it won't download.

Comment: @Bobby Hi. I have just tried, and i can't see anything that could be the reason for why it's not downloading.

Comment: My results are the same except my report is smaller and downloads quicker. Have you checked your download folder? Also I know the reports server runs badly on chrome but you can try downloading the .rdl from the manage view with it

Comment: Try clicking 'Manage' instead and see if the 'Download' toolbar button on that page works.

Comment: @JC. as i write in my qustion, i have already tried that.

Comment: Did you solve it? I think you need to run the web browser in administrative mode?